# jQuery drag and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) for re-size and drag of a div. It gives me some strange behavior like on re-size it jumps outside of container how can I fix it. Any help should be appreciated.

HTML:-

```
<div class="paper-area" id="paper_area"></div>
<div class="upload-logo drag">Upload Logo</div>
```

JS:-

```
 $(".drag").draggable({
            containment: ".paper-area",
             start: function(e, ui) {
            $(this).css({
            //   position: "relative",
            });
             },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                 containment: ".paper-area",
            $(this).css({
              // position: "relative",
            });
       },
}).resizable({
          containment: ".paper-area",
           start: function(e, ui) {
           // alert($(".paper-area").width());
            containment: ".paper-area",
            $(this).css({
             //  position: "relative",
             });
            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
            containment: ".paper-area",
            $(this).css({
               //position: "relative",
            });
            }
});
```

CSS:-

```
.paper-area {
    border: 1px solid #E4E3E3;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 48px auto 0;
    width: 400px;
}
.upload-logo {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #626262;
    color: #7B7B7B;
    height: 98px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FFFFFF;
    width: 99px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/princefiddle/BPQQN/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

There were two major problems (see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BPQQN/7/):

-the containment area did not actually contain the grey rectangle. To fix this, I changed the html to:

```
<div class="paper-area" id="paper_area">

<div class="upload-logo drag">Upload Logo</div>
 </div>
```

-the grey rectangle jumped around on drag start because it had  `margin: 0 auto;` Deleted the margin and it worked.

The current state of the fiddle is probably not what you were trying to achieve. What should be the final result?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/BPQQN/8/

html :

```
<div class="paper-area" id="paper_area">
    <div class="upload-logo drag">Upload Logo</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .upload-logo {
       position:absolute;
```